# Are Azure CosmosDB indexes split by partition

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am sending some IoT events into Azure Cosmos DB. I am partitioning by device id and I am always querying by device id. I want to know if the automatically created indexes are separated by partition key. Specifically if I do query like

```
SELECT TOP 5 ... FROM events WHERE deviceId = X ORDER BY timeStamp DESC
```

Will it use the automatically created index on timeStamp and if so is it effective. Basically what I am asking is if there are separate indexes on timeStamp for each partition key (deviceId in my case) because otherwise the index will be relatively useless because the range will contain a lot of irrelevant data from other devices. If this was SQL Server I would create an index on deviceId followed by timeStamp but I am not sure how Cosmos DB works by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indexes sit within the partition so yes.

For this query you have you should also create a composite index with DESC sort order for the best performance.

Comment: If I am only ordering by timestamp can't the index just be used in reverse? I think SQL Server would do that (obviously this is not SQL Server)

Comment: No you will need a composite index when using Order By for best performance. In fact, this may throw an exception now if there isn't one.